# Powershell Function returning blank data when setting a variable

Tags: powershell

First off, I appoligize for my terminalogy. I self taught myself powershell, so my lingo may be a bit off.

I have a script that I am running in WinPE which brings up a menu system for windows imaging (selecting image file, running a diskpart file, ect.). Part of this script looks up which volumes are visible to windows PE and prompts the user to select which volume they would like to install the image to. I separated this portion of the code into it's own function. The issue I'm having is that the WMI call to lookup the logical disks returns blank results when the function is setting a variable (see example below). But when I dot-source and run the function by itself it works fine. Here is the code i'm using

```
$Vol = Select-VolumeLetter
```

---- In a seperate file which has been dot-sourced -----

```
Function Select-VolumeLetter {
$InstallVolumes = (gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk -namespace "root\CIMV2")
$i = 1
Write-Host "`nPlease Select a volume to install the OS on:`n"
ForEach ($V in $InstallVolumes) {
    Write-Host "[$i]"
    $V | Select Name, Size, FileSystem, VolumeName | fl
    $i++
    }
Do{
    $Range = $i - 1 
    $Input = Read-Host "Choose 1-$Range"
    $Result = ""
    if(![int32]::TryParse( $Input , [ref]$Result )) {Write-Host "`nInvalid selection. Please try again.`n"}
    } until ($Result -gt 0 -and $Result -lt ($i + 1))
$InstallVolumes[($Input -1)].Name
}
```

The result looks like:

[1]

[2]

[3] ect.

But when run just as a function I get the full WMI information requested in the correct place. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show more clearly how you are defining/sourcing the function, and then calling the function, clearly delineating which way works and which doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think you have some terminology wrong. What you show is not the results, that it what appears on your screen due to the Write-Host calls. You are not seeing the WMI information because you are not specifying that it be written to the screen and it is therefore being passed back as a result of the function. In your case $Vol will contain that WMI information. I think what would fix your situation would be something like this:

```
$InstallVolumes = (gwmi Win32_LogicalDisk -namespace "root\CIMV2")
$i = 1
Write-Host "`nPlease Select a volume to install the OS on:"
ForEach ($V in $InstallVolumes) {
    Write-Host "`n[$i]"
    Write-Host ($V | Select Name, Size, FileSystem, VolumeName | fl|out-string).trim()
    $i++
    }
```

Comment: DOH! I knew I had to be doing something simple wrong. I appreciate the fix\advice! Worked great!